# Dúvida sobre herança de classes em Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, herança

Tenho o seguinte código um `ebook` que herda a classe `Livro` (superclasse).

No entanto, não consigo criar um novo `ebook` e *setar* no nome, quando coloco o método principal (`main`) dá erro.

Classe `Autor`:

```
public class Autor {
    private String nome;
    private String cpf;
    private String email;


}
```

Classe `Livro`:

```
public class Livro {
    private String nome;
    private String descricao;
    private double valor;
    private String isbn;
    private Autor autor;
    private boolean impresso;


    public Livro(Autor autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
        this.isbn = "00-000-0000-00";
        this.impresso = true;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String nome() {
        return nome;

    }

    public boolean aplicaDescontoDe(double porcentagem) {
        if(porcentagem > 0.3) { //for maior que 30%
            return false; //retorna falso;
        } else if (!this.impresso && porcentagem > 0.15){ //se livro digital e for maior que 15% de desconto
            return false; //retorna falso

        }
        this.valor -=this.valor *porcentagem; 
        return true;
    }



}
```

Classe `Ebook`:

```
public class Ebook extends Livro { 


    private String waterMark;

    public Ebook(Autor autor) {
        super(autor); //superclasse
    }

    public void setWaterMark(String weterMark) {
        this.waterMark = waterMark;

    }

    public String getWaterMark() {
        return waterMark;
    }




}
```

Não consigo chamar o `main` na classe `Ebook` e criar um novo objeto `ebook`, e definir o nome, e dá erro.

```
Ebook ebook = new Ebook() {
ebook.setNome("Bla bla bla");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparentemente sua modelagem de classes está correta, o problema que faz gerar o erro é a forma como você está tentando *setar* o conteúdo de `nome`, já que está usando uma sintaxe não válida.

Para este problema, no lugar disto:

```
Ebook ebook = new Ebook() {
    ebook.setNome("Bla bla bla");
}
```

Use isto:

```
Ebook ebook = new Ebook();
ebook.setNome("Bla bla bla");
```

Outras observações quanto ao seu código, mas que não geram erros, apenas comportamentos:

- neste trecho você não está reconfigurando o valor de `waterMark`. Você deve alterar o parâmetro de `weterMark` para `waterMark` **OU** mudar a forma de atribuição, altere disto:

```java
public void setWaterMark(String weterMark) {
    this.waterMark = waterMark;
}
```

Para isto:

```
public void setWaterMark(String waterMark) {
    this.waterMark = waterMark;
}
```

Um exemplo final seria este:

- classe `Autor` continua sem alterações;
- clase `Livro`: incluído construtor padrão (sem argumentos), então você poderá fazer `new Ebook()` sem passar instância de `Autor`;

```java
public class Livro {

    private String nome;
    private String descricao;
    private double valor;
    private String isbn;
    private Autor autor;
    private boolean impresso;

    public Livro() {}

    public Livro(final Autor autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
        isbn = "00-000-0000-00";
        impresso = true;
    }

    // getter e setters

    // demais métodos que precise

}
```

- classe `Ebook`: adicionado construtor padrão (sem argumentos) que chama o construtor padrão de `Livro`;

```java
public class Ebook extends Livro {

    private String waterMark;

    public Ebook() {
        super();
    }

    public Ebook(final Autor autor) {
        super(autor); // superclasse
    }

    // getter e setters

    // demais métodos que precise

}
```

Por fim, um exemplo de classe `Main` seria assim, criando instâncias de `Ebook` informando já na construção `Autor` e não:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Ebook ebook = new Ebook();
        ebook.setNome("Bla bla bla");

        final Autor autor = new Autor();
        autor.setNome("Nome do Autor");
        autor.setEmail("mail@mail.com");
        final Ebook ebook2 = new Ebook(autor);
        ebook2.setNome("Bla2 bla2 bla2");
    }

}
```

Comment: Ele da erro, eu crio o objeto na classe Ebook? E o main também? porque o set e get do nome(private) esta na classe Livro

Comment: @Leonardinho já atualizo a resposta, faltam alguns construtores também

Comment: @Leonardinho atualizada a resposta, veja se tem alguma dúvida sobre a modelagem =)

Comment: Ok, resolvido...

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de:

```
Ebook ebook = new Ebook() {
    ebook.setNome("Bla bla bla");
}
```

Use, sem `{` e `}`:

```
    Ebook ebook = new Ebook(autor);
    ebook.setNome("Bla bla bla");
```

Você esqueceu de **criar um novo autor** e passá-lo para o construtor do Ebook `Autor`:

```
    Autor autor = new Autor();
    autor.nome = "Felipe";
    autor.cpf = "333.333.333-22";
    autor.email = "meu@email.com";

    Ebook ebook = new Ebook(autor);
    ebook.setNome("Bla bla bla");
```

Note também que seu autor possui propriedades privadas e neste caso, devem ser públicas para você criar um novo autor:

```
public class Autor
{
    public String nome;
    public String cpf;
    public String email;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que setar os atributos como `protected` e não `private` como você esta fazendo, porque senão a `herança` não atua sobre o `atributo`.

E para setar você deve fazer:

```
Ebook ebook = new Ebook();
ebook.setNome("bla bla bla");
```